# Quicklook word Notebook layout broken

Tags: quicklook

Model Identifier: MacBookPro11,4

System Version: macOS 10.13.3 (17D102)

Microsoft. Word for Mac 2011

Version 14.7.7 (170905)

Latest Installed Update: 14.7.7

Here's the issue. I can see a quicklook for normal word files, but if I try to see them in notebook layout view, the image is blank. I have deleted a few different plist files, to no avail. Also, I restarted my computer and ran first aid on my disk utility. Furthermore, I tried to select get info and change the default program to preview. It refused to open, so that was no good.

This is a uniform problem, it doesn't work on any of my .docx as long as they are in notebook layout. I have audio recordings embedded in most of them FYI.

Also, just as a side note, the clipart doesn't work either.

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me fix this, I was thinking maybe there's a quicklook plugin?

Link to original thread: https://discussions.apple.com/message/33131142#33131142

Comment: This is probably a bug in macOS, and not a problem with your computer. You should file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com if you are a developer, or send feedback at https://www.apple.com/feedback/ if you are an end-user.

Comment: Can you post the notebook file online somewhere? It looks like this template does not exist in Word 2016 anymore.

Comment: Seems like when I create a new file it might work. Maybe just the old files are now broken (ever since I tried fixing the plist). I'll post if I have more trouble. THank you all for the help.